# Mirror to X not working (Weight Painting)

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Hi Mirror to X isn't working. How do I fix this?

I'm using v2.83

[image]

Comment: You need to select the axis to mirror on. Press the X under the symmetry tab.

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)